# XCode 11.1 simulator can't install target iOS Version

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I have a question about install simulator.
I download the iOS 11.3 & 11.2 , but I can't chose iOS version about simulator. 
I want to build my app in these iOS version.
What's wrong with my step.
ps: MacOS Big Sur

[image: iOS]

Comment: Did you try restarting the computer?

Comment: Yes, I already restart.